# split("\n") doesn't work, nor throws errors

Tags: ruby, bash

I was writing ruby code to fix a few files in my bigger C project.
And I wrote this -

```
x = `find $PWD/ | grep "\.h"`
x = x.split("\n")
...
```

My code NEVER splits at a new line, why is this?

[image]

Comment: What is the value of x.count?

Comment: Show an example of the result of `find $PWD/ | grep "\.h"`

Comment: @YuHao Could you take a look now?

Comment: So what is the value of `x` before and after the split?

Comment: @ndn it's the same ,  somehow

Comment: @ShaheAnsar, how do you know that it's the same? Did you `puts` it? Try `p x` instead

Comment: @ndn I tried,  it's the same

Comment: @ShaheAnsar, that is simply not possible. `String#split` returns an array. If you save the first result to a different variable and compare `x == y` what do you get?

Comment: @ndn ir returns false

Comment: Not a screenshot, show an actual string, that you got in `irb`. In another word, show something that people can reproduce.

Comment: @ShaheAnsar, ok so now - what do `p x` and `p y` print individually?

Comment: @ndn one returns a strung, one returns an array with a single element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You splitting is OK and you have not brought the evidence it was not, but your shell command will probably not do what you expect, so let me comment on it.

You apparently want a list of C header files (files ending with `.h`) however:

- `$PWD` is not quoted which will cause you troubles if you have white-spaces in `$PWD` => `find` will think there are several directories in parameters
- your `\.h` will be unquoted by ruby and passed as just `.h` to `grep`, witch means "any character followed by 'h'". Use `grep -F .h` for a literal search.
- your `grep` will search for a `.h` anywhere in the string. If you only want files ending with `.h` you must grep for `.h$` (with `grep` then, not `grep -F`)
- don't `find+grep`, just find by name: `find -name "<pattern>"`. Easier, lighter, safer.
- you may want to protect your code from file names containing a line-feed character => have `find` separate the filenames with `\0` and split on this character instead
- what about environment where lines do not end with `\n` (LF) but with CR-LF or just CR? => `find -print0` again

Here is what the resulting program should be IMHO:

```
x = `find "$PWD" -name "*.h" -print0`
x = x.split("\0")
```

Comment: It works, somehow, it was my terminal's fault, using a different one works

Comment: Note: `-print0` is a non-standard extension. Not all `find`s have it.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to launch a subshell, Ruby comes with [`Dir.glob`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Dir.html#method-c-glob):

```
header_files = File.join(Dir.pwd, '**', '*.h')
x = Dir.glob(header_files)
```

You can omit [`Dir.pwd`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Dir.html#method-c-pwd) if relative paths are okay.